# Custom _error page with Sentry for error catching does not work in Next.js v13

Tags: node.js, reactjs, logging, next.js, sentry

**Q: How to make a custom _error page with Sentry to catch all 404 and other errors?**

Versions:

- **Next.js v13.1**
- **Node v16.16.0**
- **Typescript Version 4.7.3**

The custom _error page does not catch any errors.

I have followed this guide from Sentry for Next.js: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#create-a-custom-_error-page

My _error.tsx page:

```js
/**
 * NOTE: This requires `@sentry/nextjs` version 7.3.0 or higher.
 *
 * This page is loaded by Nextjs:
 *  - on the server, when data-fetching methods throw or reject
 *  - on the client, when `getInitialProps` throws or rejects
 *  - on the client, when a React lifecycle method throws or rejects, and it's
 *    caught by the built-in Nextjs error boundary
 *
 * See:
 *  - https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/overview
 *  - https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props
 *  - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html
 */

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';
import type { NextPage } from 'next';
import type { ErrorProps } from 'next/error';
import NextErrorComponent from 'next/error';

const CustomErrorComponent: NextPage<ErrorProps> = (props) => {
  // If you're using a Nextjs version prior to 12.2.1, uncomment this to
  // compensate for https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8592
  // Sentry.captureUnderscoreErrorException(props);

  return <NextErrorComponent statusCode={props.statusCode} />;
};

CustomErrorComponent.getInitialProps = async (contextData) => {
  // In case this is running in a serverless function, await this in order to give Sentry
  // time to send the error before the lambda exits
  await Sentry.captureUnderscoreErrorException(contextData);
  console.log('getInitialProps in _error.tsx')

  // This will contain the status code of the response
  return NextErrorComponent.getInitialProps(contextData);
};

export default CustomErrorComponent;
```

My `next.config.js` file:

```js
const { withSentryConfig } = require('@sentry/nextjs');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    ENV_FLAVOR: process.env.ENV_FLAVOR,
  },
  sentry: {
    // Use `hidden-source-map` rather than `source-map` as the Webpack `devtool`
    // for client-side builds. (This will be the default starting in
    // `@sentry/nextjs` version 8.0.0.) See
    // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/ and
    // https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/manual-setup/#use-hidden-source-map
    // for more information.
    hideSourceMaps: true,
  },
  // Use the CDN in production and localhost for development.
  assetPrefix: '[redacted]',
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['pages', 'components', 'utils', 'hooks', 'server'],
  },
  images: {
    domains: [
      '[redacted]',
    ],
  },
  output: 'standalone',

  // https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack
  // SVGR - enables to write .svg files as components with className, etc. - <Icon className='' {...props} />
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@svgr/webpack',
          options: {
            typescript: true,
            icon: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return config;
  },
};

const sentryWebpackPluginOptions = {
  enabled: true,
  // Additional config options for the Sentry Webpack plugin. Keep in mind that
  // the following options are set automatically, and overriding them is not
  // recommended:
  //   release, url, org, project, authToken, configFile, stripPrefix,
  //   urlPrefix, include, ignore
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry.[redacted]',
  authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
  debug: true,
  silent: false, // Suppresses all logs
  // For all available options, see:
  // https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-webpack-plugin#options.
};

module.exports = withSentryConfig(nextConfig, sentryWebpackPluginOptions)
```

My `sentry.client.config.js` file:

```js
// This file configures the initialization of Sentry on the browser.
// The config you add here will be used whenever a page is visited.
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';

const SENTRY_DSN = process.env.SENTRY_DSN || process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN;

Sentry.init({
  enabled: true,
  dsn: SENTRY_DSN || 'https://[redacted]@sentry.[redacted]/[redacted]',
  environment: process.env.ENV_FLAVOR || process.env.NODE_ENV,
  // Adjust this value in production, or use tracesSampler for greater control
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  debug: true,
  silent: false, // Suppresses all logs

  // ...
  // Note: if you want to override the automatic release value, do not set a
  // `release` value here - use the environment variable `SENTRY_RELEASE`, so
  // that it will also get attached to your source maps
});
```

My `sentry.server.config.js` file:

```js
// This file configures the initialization of Sentry on the server.
// The config you add here will be used whenever the server handles a request.
// https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/nextjs/

import * as Sentry from '@sentry/nextjs';

const SENTRY_DSN = process.env.SENTRY_DSN || process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENTRY_DSN;

Sentry.init({
  enabled: true,
  dsn: SENTRY_DSN || 'https://[redacted]@sentry.[redacted]/[redacted]',
  // Adjust this value in production, or use tracesSampler for greater control
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  debug: true
  silent: false, // Suppresses all logs

  // ...
  // Note: if you want to override the automatic release value, do not set a
  // `release` value here - use the environment variable `SENTRY_RELEASE`, so
  // that it will also get attached to your source maps
});
```

Run `yarn dev` log:

```
[07:09:41] Starting compilation in watch mode...

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from /[redacted]/.env
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DRY Run Mode
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DRY Run Mode
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DRY Run Mode
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Injecting release code
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Loaders:
 [
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  'next-image-loader',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '@svgr/webpack',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added loaders:
 [
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed loaders:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Entry:

[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Injecting release code
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Loaders:
 [
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  'next-image-loader',
  '@svgr/webpack',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/proxyLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added loaders:
 [
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed loaders:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Entry:

[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Injecting release code
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Loaders:
 [
  '<unknown loader>',
  'next-middleware-asset-loader',
  'next-middleware-wasm-loader',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '<unknown loader>',
  'next-image-loader',
  '<unknown loader>',
  '@svgr/webpack',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/valueInjectionLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/config/loaders/proxyLoader.js',
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added loaders:
 [
  '/[redacted]/node_modules/@sentry/webpack-plugin/src/sentry.loader.js'
]
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed loaders:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Entry:

[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Added entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] DEBUG: Removed entry:
 []
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/static/chunks/pages'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/static/chunks/pages'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
event - compiled client and server successfully in 3.6s (689 modules)
[07:09:47] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

wait  - compiling /middleware (client and server)...
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
event - compiled successfully in 161 ms (41 modules)
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/static/chunks/pages'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/static/chunks/pages'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
event - compiled client and server successfully in 501 ms (689 modules)
Sentry Logger [log]: Initializing SDK...
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: InboundFilters
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: FunctionToString
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Console
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Http
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: OnUncaughtException
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: OnUnhandledRejection
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: ContextLines
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Context
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Modules
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: RequestData
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: LinkedErrors
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: Postgres
Sentry Logger [log]: Integration installed: RewriteFrames
Sentry Logger [log]: SDK successfully initialized
warn  - You have added a custom /_error page without a custom /404 page. This prevents the 404 page from being auto statically optimized.
See here for info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/custom-error-no-custom-404
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - /_error
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'function.nextjs' span on transaction '/_error' (aa456f6d383caa73).
getInitialProps in _error.tsx
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'function.nextjs' span on transaction '/_error' (aa456f6d383caa73).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing http.server transaction: /_error.
Sentry Logger [log]: Flushing events...
Sentry Logger [log]: Done flushing events
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Continuing trace 7a3dfcb765b743ac893c35809336ad1b.
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - GET /api/auth/session
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Continuing trace 7a3dfcb765b743ac893c35809336ad1b.
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - GET /api/auth/session
wait  - compiling /api/auth/[...nextauth] (client and server)...
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
event - compiled successfully in 186 ms (156 modules)
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Creating new release:
 'development'
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Calling upload-sourcemaps with:
 {
  finalize: true,
  rewrite: true,
  include: [
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/pages/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/pages'
    },
    {
      paths: [
        '/[redacted]/.next/server/chunks/'
      ],
      urlPrefix: '~/_next/server/chunks'
    }
  ],
  ignore: [],
  configFile: 'sentry.properties',
  stripPrefix: [ 'webpack://_N_E/' ],
  urlPrefix: '~/_next',
  entries: [Function: entries],
  release: 'development',
  dryRun: true,
  enabled: true,
  org: '[redacted]',
  project: '[redacted]',
  url: 'https://sentry./[redacted]',
  environment: 'development',
  authToken: '[redacted]',
  debug: true,
  silent: false
}
[Sentry Webpack Plugin] Finalizing release:
 'development'
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Continuing trace 7a3dfcb765b743ac893c35809336ad1b.
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Continuing trace 7a3dfcb765b743ac893c35809336ad1b.
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]
query: SELECT * FROM current_schema()
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
query: SHOW server_version;
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
query: SELECT "user"."id" AS "user_id", "user"."name" AS "user_name", "user"."email" AS "user_email", "user"."profile_picture" AS "user_profile_picture", "user"."created_at" AS "user_created_at", "user"."updated_at" AS "user_updated_at", "user"."bio" AS "user_bio", "user"."job_title" AS "user_job_title", "user"."linkedin_url" AS "user_linkedin_url", "user"."twitter_url" AS "user_twitter_url", "user"."website" AS "user_website", "user"."company_name" AS "user_company_name", "user"."company_size" AS "user_company_size", "socials"."id" AS "socials_id", "socials"."name" AS "socials_name", "socials"."nickname" AS "socials_nickname", "socials"."profile_picture" AS "socials_profile_picture", "socials"."email" AS "socials_email", "socials"."provider" AS "socials_provider", "socials"."userId" AS "socials_userId", "votes"."id" AS "votes_id", "votes"."vote_type" AS "votes_vote_type", "votes"."session_id" AS "votes_session_id", "votes"."created_at" AS "votes_created_at", "votes"."updated_at" AS "votes_updated_at", "votes"."user_id" AS "votes_user_id", "votes"."article_id" AS "votes_article_id" FROM "users" "user" LEFT JOIN "social_accounts" "socials" ON "socials"."userId"="user"."id"  LEFT JOIN "article_votes" "votes" ON "votes"."user_id"="user"."id" WHERE "user"."email" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["[redacted]"]
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (a471a31253c2516e).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (a471a31253c2516e).
query: SELECT "user"."id" AS "user_id", "user"."name" AS "user_name", "user"."email" AS "user_email", "user"."profile_picture" AS "user_profile_picture", "user"."created_at" AS "user_created_at", "user"."updated_at" AS "user_updated_at", "user"."bio" AS "user_bio", "user"."job_title" AS "user_job_title", "user"."linkedin_url" AS "user_linkedin_url", "user"."twitter_url" AS "user_twitter_url", "user"."website" AS "user_website", "user"."company_name" AS "user_company_name", "user"."company_size" AS "user_company_size", "socials"."id" AS "socials_id", "socials"."name" AS "socials_name", "socials"."nickname" AS "socials_nickname", "socials"."profile_picture" AS "socials_profile_picture", "socials"."email" AS "socials_email", "socials"."provider" AS "socials_provider", "socials"."userId" AS "socials_userId", "votes"."id" AS "votes_id", "votes"."vote_type" AS "votes_vote_type", "votes"."session_id" AS "votes_session_id", "votes"."created_at" AS "votes_created_at", "votes"."updated_at" AS "votes_updated_at", "votes"."user_id" AS "votes_user_id", "votes"."article_id" AS "votes_article_id" FROM "users" "user" LEFT JOIN "social_accounts" "socials" ON "socials"."userId"="user"."id"  LEFT JOIN "article_votes" "votes" ON "votes"."user_id"="user"."id" WHERE "user"."email" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: ["[redacted]"]
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing http.server transaction: GET /api/auth/[...nextauth].
Sentry Logger [log]: Flushing events...
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'db' span on transaction 'GET /api/auth/[...nextauth]' (ab9317efe6069f6b).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing http.server transaction: GET /api/auth/[...nextauth].
Sentry Logger [log]: Flushing events...
Sentry Logger [log]: Done flushing events
Sentry Logger [log]: Done flushing events
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Continuing trace 7a3dfcb765b743ac893c35809336ad1b.
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - /some-non-existing-page
Sentry Logger [log]: Initializing SDK...
Sentry Logger [log]: SDK already initialized
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] starting http.server transaction - /_error
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Starting 'function.nextjs' span on transaction '/_error' (a3bef10759093a80).
getInitialProps in _error.tsx
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing 'function.nextjs' span on transaction '/_error' (a3bef10759093a80).
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing http.server transaction: /_error.
Sentry Logger [log]: Flushing events...
Sentry Logger [log]: Done flushing events
Sentry Logger [log]: [Tracing] Finishing http.server transaction: /_error.
```

Rendered page:
[image: 404 error page]

### A workaround I don't want to use:

Just a note here that I don't want to use `return { notFound: true }` (ref: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#notfound) in all pages because it logs a weird error in Sentry that doesn't say anything.

[image: not helpful error in Sentry]